# Unable to loop through connected objects on realm swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am completely flumixed as to what and why this is happening.  However, following the tutorials, this should not be happening.

I am getting the following error "Referencing initializer 'init(_:id:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that 'RLMSwiftCollectionBase' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'"

I obviously cannot update RLMSwiftCollectionBase since that is part of the library.  And it would defeat a primary purpose of linking if I couldn't loop through like this.  Not to mention, I have seen at least one tutorial that shows this working.  Given that nobody else seems to be facing an issue, looping either, everyone else knows not to do it, or I am missing something blindingly obvious.  Please help.

```
struct EditProfileView: View {
    @ObservedRealmObject var profile: ProfileModel
    @ObservedRealmObject var status: StatusModel

    init(ProfileId id: UUID) {
//I'm aware this is improper, and would appreciate suggestions, however, my focus has been on trying to get this to compile.
        profile = RealmManager.shared.getProfile(id) ?? ProfileModel(Name: "Unknown")
        status = RealmManager.shared.getStatus()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
//ERROR OCCURS HERE
             ForEach(profile.lists, id: \.id) { item in
                            ProfileSettingListView(Profile: _profile, List: item)
                                .id(item.id)
                        }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                            withAnimation {
                                profile.lists.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                            }
                        })
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
            .background(Color(red: 0.47, green: 0.47, blue: 0.5).opacity(0.16))
    }
}
```

```
struct ProfileSettingListView: View {
    @ObservedRealmObject var profile: ProfileModel
    @ObservedRealmObject var list: ProfileListModel
    @State var showConfirmation: Bool = false
    @State var showFas: Bool = false

    init(Profile profile: ObservedRealmObject<ProfileModel>, List list: ObservedRealmObject<ProfileListModel>) {
        _profile = profile
        _list = list
    }

    var body: some View {
        Section {
            Text("Test")

        } header: {
            if list.name == nil || list.name!.isEmpty {
                Text(list.style.description)
            } else {
                HStack {
                    Text(list.name!)
                    Spacer()
                    Text(list.style.description)
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class ProfileModel: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable, Identifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) public var id: UUID
    @Persisted public var name: String
    @Persisted public var lists: List<ProfileListModel>

    init(Name _name: String = "Profile 1") {
        super.init()
        id = UUID()
    }
}
```

```
class ProfileListModel: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable, Identifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) public var id: UUID = UUID()
    @Persisted public var enabled: Bool = true
    @Persisted public var name: String? = nil

}
```

Comment: I may be overlooking something but `ProfileSettingListView(Profile: _profile, List: item)` would more be `ProfileSettingListView(profile: _profile, list: item)`. Also, the `class ProfileModel` init of `init(Name _name: String = "Profile 1")` should be `convenience init() { self.init... `. Along with allowing the primaryKey to init itself - no need to manually do it, same with the name var, just name = "Profile 1" - so the init function isn't really needed..